# MBProgressHUD and StartUpdateLocation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to show the activity HUD while getting GPS location but it is not working.
The hud doesn't show. Any idea why it isn't showing? It is just not showing on startupdatinglocation. The rest of the call is fine.

```
[HUD show:YES];
// start fetching data from a remote API
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.tabBarController.view animated:YES];` to show mine. You need to tell it which view too show it on by changing `self.tabBarController.view` to `self.view` or `self.navigationController.view`